# Python Pandas: Change format in which index and column names and corresponding values are the new row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a format change in a dataframe, but I want to this in the most efficient way possible: Lets say I have a dataframe like this:

```
     A     B
1    10    11
2    12    13
```

I want to convert this into this dataframe:

```
Location  Value
[1,A]     10
[1,B]     11
[2,A]     12
[2,B]     13
```

Thank you=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make do with `stack` and `reset_index`:

```
new_df = df.stack()
new_df['Location'] = [x for x in new_df.index]
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```